# Angular how to display data inside every part of doughnut chartjs

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

how to display data inside every part of doughnut chartjs with angular i make a code like this but it did not work

```
 public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = [
    'Demo',
    'Test',
    'Live',


  ];

  public dougnutChartPlugins=[this.doughnutChartLabels];
public  doughnutChartLegend=true;
  doughnutChartData = [];
  
  public doughnutChartColors: any[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor: ['#735A84', '#E76412', '#9BC311',],
    },
  ];
  public chartLabels: Array<any> = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];

  public doughnutChartType = 'doughnut';
  public doughnutChartOptions: any = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
   
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        font: {
          weight: 'bold',
          size: 19
        }
      }
    }   
  };
```

and my html like this

```
<canvas baseChart class="chart" [data]="doughnutChartData" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                      [options]="doughnutChartOptions" [chartType]="doughnutChartType"                      
                       [legend]="doughnutChartLegend"
                       [plugins]="dougnutChartPlugins"
                      [colors]="doughnutChartColors">
                                       </canvas>
```

i found something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H8kG.png)

but i want something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1O55.png)

i need some helps and thank ylu

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default in chart.js so you will need a plugin for this, a great plugin to use is the [`datalabels plugin`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html)

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

const options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => (ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex]),
        color: '#fff',
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: works the same, still need to install and register the plugin etc